# PYQT5 How to open a new window by date "mon" , "tues", etc

Tags: python, calendar, pyqt5, new-window

how do I open a new window after selecting the date on the calendar? Where I will be able to open different windows according to dates?

Below is my code:
I've tried using if-else but I couldn't fetch the data. How can I open a new window by reading the word from the label that fetches the calendar data?

```
class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height = 600, 100, 500, 480

        self.page1 = self.create_page1()
        self.page2 = self.create_page2()

        self.stack = QStackedWidget()
        self.stack.addWidget(self.page1)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.page2)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(self.stack)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.show_page1()

        self.show()


    def create_page1(self):
        page = QWidget()


        page.calendar = QCalendarWidget(page)
        page.calendar.setGridVisible(True)
        page.calendar.selectionChanged.connect(self.onSelectionChanged)

        page.label = QLabel(page)
        #page.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sanserif", 10))
        page.label.setStyleSheet('color: blue;')

        page.proceedbutton = QPushButton("Proceed to select time", page)
        page.proceedbutton.setToolTip("<h3>Start the Session</h3>")
        page.proceedbutton.setEnabled(False)
        page.proceedbutton.clicked.connect(self.show_page2)

        page.backbutton = QPushButton("Back", page)
        page.backbutton.setToolTip("<h3>Start the Session</h3>")

        page.comboBox = None

        page.grid = QGridLayout(page)
        page.grid.addWidget(page.calendar, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        page.grid.addWidget(page.label, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        page.grid.addWidget(page.backbutton, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        page.grid.addWidget(page.proceedbutton, 2, 2, 1, 1)

        return page

    def create_page2(self):
        page = QWidget()

        layout = QFormLayout(page)

        page.comboBox = QComboBox(page)
        page.comboBox.addItems(["choose time", "0700", "0800"])
        page.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.onComboActivated)
        layout.addRow('Choose Time', page.comboBox)

        page.viewbutton = QPushButton("View Stalls", page)
        page.viewbutton.setEnabled(False)
        page.viewbutton.clicked.connect(self.show_page3)
        layout.addRow(page.viewbutton)

        page.reselectdatebutton = QPushButton("Return to re-select date", page)
        page.reselectdatebutton.clicked.connect(self.show_page1)
        layout.addRow(page.reselectdatebutton)

        return page


    def show_page1(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Select date from calendar")
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def show_page2(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Select Time")
        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 500, 480)

        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def show_page3(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("View Stalls")
        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 500, 480)
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(2)



    def onSelectionChanged(self):

        ca = self.page1.calendar.selectedDate()
        self.page1.label.setText(ca.toString())
        print(ca.toString())
        self.page1.proceedbutton.setEnabled(True)


    def onComboActivated(self, text):
        print("choose time: {}".format(text))
        self.page2.viewbutton.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Your example does not meet any requirement for a [minimal, *reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, you're using an `if` statement to test against a function reference (`onSelectionChanged`), which doesn't make any sense at all; also, there's some syntax errors and references to unknown objects (such as `page.backButton`). Can you better check your own code and edit your question to allow us to successfully test your example and then try to give you an answer and an explanation?

Comment: Hi @musicamante I've edited my code, I've tried using if-else to open the pages I want it to open according to the days. However, it doesn't seem to read the words i want it to read...

Comment: You shouldn't use toString() to check for comparison, as its output could change according to system settings (and localization). If you want to check against the week day, use QDate.weekDay(). That said, your example is still *not* reproducible: there's a reference to an object that doesn't exist (`if page.labeldate =="Mon":`), and, even if it worked, it will always connect to the first match found when creating the page. You should connect to a function that checks the *current* date, and then switch to the page you want.

Comment: hi @musicamante if i write the code this way:

    def onSelectionChanged(self):

        ca = self.page1.calendar.selectedDate()
        self.page1.label.setText(ca.toString())
        print(self.QCalendarWidget.weekDay())
        self.page1.proceedbutton.setEnabled(True)

I'm not able to retrieve the day from the print area tho?

Comment: @musicamante i've re-edited my code should be able to run . However i'm still having problem using weekday()

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. What do you need the week day for? What is the expected behavior and what error/issue do you get? If you're not precise with your description, we cannot help you much...

Comment: @musicamante I would like to click the viewmenubutton to view menu according to the different days on page 3 . the expected output was to open a menu on monday and a total different menu on tuesday !! according to the selected date from the calendar widget. sorry for the unclear description!

Comment: I've added a possible answer to your (sorry, I've to say it) still a bit confusing question. Btw, I've to apologize: I made a mistake writing about an unexisting `QDate.weekDay()` function, while what I meant obviously was `QDate.dayOfWeek()`. In any case, just get yourself some time and study the official [Qt classes documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html) anytime you have some doubt. I know it might seem a bit overwhelming (expecially if you don't know anything about C++), but it really is worth the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do a different action according to the week day, all you need to do is to connect the `clicked` signal to a function that will use the [`QCalendar.selectedDate().dayOfWeek()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#dayOfWeek) (which has a `range(1, 8)`).

```
class Window(QWidget):
    # ...
    def create_page3(self):
        # ...
        page.viewmenubutton.clicked.connect(self.openviewforday)

    def openviewforday(self):
        weekDay = self.page1.calendar.selectedDate().dayOfWeek()
        if weekDay == 1:
            # do something for Monday
        elif weekDay == 2:
            # do something for Tuesday
        # etc...
```

Comment: Oh!!! I got it !!! Thank you so much for the useful information! @musicamante